# Como fazer para pegar o conteúdo do meu array em ordem crescente das keys

Tags: javascript, array

Estou com um problema em uma função de um app que estou criando. 
Sou um mero novato em programação buscando aperfeiçoar meu conhecimento e queria saber como fazer para que minha função pegue o conteúdo das keys do meu array em ordem crescente destas.

**Exemplo:**

```
var exemplo = {
    "1":"chave1",
    "2":"chave2",
    "3":"chave3"
}
```

> Nesse caso, eu queria que ele pegasse o conteúdo das keys em ordem
>   crescente e, ao chegar na última key, voltasse para a primeira em criando um loop.

Assim, retornando o valor da minha key "1", depois da "2" e "3", voltando ao começo e repetindo o processo.
É um método mais útil do que pegar um valor *random* usando o *Math* já que eu queria que fosse em ordem e não aleatoriamente.

Comment: Como você tentou fazer? Poste seu código junto a pergunta e descreva qual é o problema que está tendo.

Comment: Não está muito claro pra mim o que você está tentando fazer e qual é o objetivo final.